# CSS: Centering DIV

Tags: css, sharepoint, html

I am having a problem with horizontally centering a DIV.

I have provided a full example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ed135/Q4Pk2/15/).

This is inside a Content Editor WebPart in SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/139010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hdA7d/

```
<div class="weathercontainer">
        <div id="weather" class="items" onClick="window.open( 'http://www.weather.com/weather/today/33196','_blank' ); return false;  " >
        </div> 
</div>


.weathercontainer{
    width: 100%;
}
.items {
    width: 170px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/xQacd/)**

**css**

```
.center
{
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.center div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the absolutely positioned `.items` a left and right position of 0 and a margin of auto:

```
.items {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q4Pk2/20/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.
[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharbandal/xx2Jk/2/)

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```